# Building a retry mechanism in a while loop in python

Tags: python, error-handling, python-requests

```
while true:
    ticker = binance.fetch_ticker("BTC/USDT")
    current_price = ticker['last']
function_A(current_price)
```

I have a while loop that keeps running to check the current price of Bitcoin every second. Then I also have a function that takes current_price as an input.

However, occasionally, I am getting

"requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))"

So I'm trying to use try, except to make a retry mechanism whenever this error comes up.
I've tried this:

```
while true:
    try_count = 10
    while try_count > 0:
        try:
            ticker = binance.fetch_ticker("BTC/USDT")
            current_price = ticker['last']
            try_count = 0
            break
        except (requests.ConnectionError, requests.ReadTimeout) as error:
            print(error, " detected. Trying again...")
            try_count -= 1
    function_A(current_price)
```

The problem is that if I do this, current_price ends up being undefined when I plug it in as an input in function_A on the last line. How can I fix this mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining `current_price` in a scope outside the second while loop can prevent the problem with `current_price` sometimes being undefined when calling `function_A`.

```
while True:
    current_price = None
    try_count = 10
    while try_count > 0:
        try:
            ticker = binance.fetch_ticker("BTC/USDT")
            current_price = ticker['last']
            try_count = 0
            break
        except (requests.ConnectionError, requests.ReadTimeout) as error:
            print(error, " detected. Trying again...")
            try_count -= 1
    if current_price is not None:
        function_A(current_price)
```

Comment: So far, it's working without an error but I'll need to check in later. Thanks for your help! If I had another input for function_A named "amount," would I just add amount = None after the second line? Then say, "if current_price is not None and amount is not None:" for the last if-loop?

Comment: Yes. That would work

Comment: Thanks again! I am curious though how this works. What is the point of saying current_price = None in the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

you may want to explore the backoff library which helps to retry your function.
https://pypi.org/project/backoff/

you can just add  a `backoff` decorator on `fetch_ticker` function and it should retries when it hits `RequestException` error.

the code should look something like

```
@backoff.on_exception(backoff.expo, requests.exceptions.RequestException)
def fetch_ticker(ticker):
    # binance.fetch_ticker
```

Comment: This looks promising but I'm definitely going to need to search some examples of it being used. Thanks for the pointer!